# How to force typescript to ignore node_modules in Next 13

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm building a website in next 13 with typescript, src folder, and app directory. When I `npm run dev` everything works as expected but once I build I get this error...

```
./node_modules/next-auth/src/core/lib/assert.ts:134:27
Type error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Adapter'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Adapter'.

  132 |       "useVerificationToken",
  133 |       "getUserByEmail",
> 134 |     ].filter((method) => !adapter[method])
      |                           ^
  135 |
  136 |     if (missingMethods.length) {
  137 |       return new MissingAdapterMethods(
```

Which leads me to believe it is the build process/typescript attempting to process the node_modules directory.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/**/*"]
    },
    "types": [],
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next13-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@motionone/utils": "^10.15.1",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.6",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.14.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/node": "20.1.3",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.10",
    "next": "13.4.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.4.3",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
    "prisma": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

After researching the issue online most were saying to add the `"skipLibCheck": true` option in the tsconfig. That is pre-defined, so I looked around some more and some were saying to add excludes which led me to add.

```
"./node_modules",
"./node_modules/*",
"./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
```

Here is my auth>[...nextauth]>route.ts file

```
import {prisma} from '../../../../lib/prisma'
import {PrismaAdapter} from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import type {NextAuthOptions} from 'next-auth'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        session: async ({ session, token }) => {
            if (session?.user) {
                // @ts-ignore
                session.user.id = token.uid!;
            }
            return session;
        },
        jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
            if (user) {
                token.uid = user.id!;
            }
            return token;
        },
    },
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export {
    handler as GET,
    handler as POST,
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you use the `next-auth` package?

Comment: The standard way as far as i'm aware. You add it into src>app>api>auth>[...nextauth].ts. Then add session provider to a layout. Finally you access the data in a component or api route with useSession/useServerSession, etc

Comment: Having exact same issue now. There's github issue also: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7721

Comment: Had to add `"noImplicitAny": false` to tsconfig compilerOptions

Comment: Ok, it appeared that I used import from 'next-auth/src/..' in one place. That triggered this error and related for me. Maybe that's the case for you as well

Answer (score -2):

You can put `ignoreBuildErrors: true` inside `next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {
  typescript: {
    // !! WARN !!
    // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has type errors.
    // !! WARN !!
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

[Refer the NextJS Documentation.](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/typescript)